# CDI @Tansactional doesn't work on JAX-RS class

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-rs, cdi, transactional

I have such method:

```
@Transactional
    @PUT
    @Path("/{servicePointNumber : \\d+}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response updateServicePoint( @PathParam("userId") Long userId,
                                        @PathParam("servicePointNumber") Integer servicePointNumber,
                                        ServicePoint servicePoint,
                                        @BeanParam GenericBeanParam params) throws ForbiddenException, UnprocessableEntityException, InternalServerErrorException {

        if(params.getAuthToken() == null) throw new ForbiddenException("Unauthorized access to web service.");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "updating existing Service Point by executing ProviderResource.ServicePointResource.updateServicePoint(servicePoint) method of REST API");

        // set resource ID passed in path param on updated resource object
        Provider foundProvider = providerFacade.find(userId);
        servicePoint.setProvider(foundProvider);
        servicePoint.setServicePointNumber(servicePointNumber);

        ServicePoint updatedServicePoint = null;
        try {
            // reflect updated resource object in database
            updatedServicePoint = servicePointFacade.update(servicePoint);
            // populate created resource with hypermedia links
            pl.salonea.jaxrs.ServicePointResource.populateWithHATEOASLinks(updatedServicePoint, params.getUriInfo());

        } catch (EJBTransactionRolledbackException ex) {
            ExceptionHandler.handleEJBTransactionRolledbackException(ex);
        } catch (EJBException ex) {
            ExceptionHandler.handleEJBException(ex);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(ExceptionHandler.ENTITY_UPDATE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(updatedServicePoint).build();
    }
```

And this method is defined inside **ServicePointResource** class of JAX-RS layer. This is inner class of **ProviderResource** class. 
The problem here is that the code throws exception:

```
Transaction aimed at persisting entity instance has been rolled back: detached entity passed to persist: pl.salonea.entities.Provider
```

Provider is @ManyToOne association with ServicePoint and moreover Provider ID is part of ServicePoint composite Primary Key.

If I move this part:

```
// set resource ID passed in path param on updated resource object
            Provider foundProvider = providerFacade.find(userId);
            servicePoint.setProvider(foundProvider);
            servicePoint.setServicePointNumber(servicePointNumber);

            ServicePoint updatedServicePoint = null;
            try {
                // reflect updated resource object in database
                updatedServicePoint = servicePointFacade.update(servicePoint);
```

to external EJB class that is @Stateless session bean and has default Transaction Management of type REQUIRED this will update correctly and error with detach method doesn't appear. **So I suppose this @Transactional annotation demarcation on above method has no effect and doesn't work!**

Comment: What does providerFacade look like and how is it being instantiated here?

Comment: It is DAO implemented as \@Stateless EJB and is Injected using \@Inject